# Operating methods in resolving derivatives - Compound functions and Quotients

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have two questions to ask about derivatives of Compound functions and Quotients :

1) My professor suggested to start from the inside and go outwards while solving compound functions derivatives, while I saw in a couple of sites I've checked that it's suggested to do otherwise, so start from the inside and go outwards, as I've solved a little number of exercises I wanted to ask which one was suggested in the most objective way, although it may differ from a person to another.

2) There is a formula for solving derivatives of divisions, but I was thinking if it was better to see the dividing term as elevated to minus one thus using the product formula and which is more immediate and shorter. Can this be applied to all cases? Is it always better to proceed  seeing it as a product?

Thank you in advance and sorry for possible mistakes I made while writing.

Answer (score 0):

at 1) In automatic differentiation this is known as the forward and backward mode.

- There is no difference if the number of input and output variables is about equal.
- If there is one output and multiple inputs, then the backward mode, or from outside to inside, is more efficient. Which is what for instance backprop neural networks use to compute gradient information.
- Reversely, few variables to many outputs is a case for the forward mode, or inside-out. Computing derivatives at multiple sampling points in the numerical integration of a differential equation could be one large-scale example.

at 2) If you reduce the quotient formula as
$$
\left(\frac pq\right)' =\frac{p'}{q}-\frac{pq'}{q^2},
$$
then there is no essential difference.

Comment: 1) I'm not doing automatic differentiation, I'm doing normal one variable differentiation exercises...does what you wrote apply here too?

Comment: Then the first remark applies: It does not matter. One could recommend to get solid in one method, disregarding the other. -- If one is discussing the merits of computational methods, it helps to clarify what the method is. And nothing makes that more clear than teaching a computer to do it, eliminating all intuitive leaps. However, intuitive leaps is what makes manual computation faster.